# Display author URL in single.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

How can I display the author website in 'single.php' template, only if the author has entered a URL in her/his profile.

I'm displaying the URL in 'author.php' but the same code doesn't work in other templates.

Thanks

Comment: Care to post your codes?

Answer (score 1):

From the WP Forum: [Displaying user profile's website field](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/284552)

`<a href="<?php echo get_usermeta($post->post_author,'user_url'); ?>">HERE</a>`